# How to properly set the column count/cell size of StaggeredGrid based on screen configuration

Tags: android, configuration, screen, staggered-gridview, etsy

I'm using the [AndroidStaggeredGrid](https://github.com/etsy/AndroidStaggeredGrid) by Etsy and want to support different screens by providing appropriate columns count and cell size. Each cell of the grid contains an `ImageView` and some text.
Following the official documentation ([screens support](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html) and [screen sizes](http://developer.android.com/training/multiscreen/screensizes.html)) I create the following folder structure:

```
values/
    integers.xml
values-small/
    integers.xml
values-large/
    integers.xml
values-xlarge/
    integers.xml
```

The content of `integers.xml` is as follows (for each configuration I just change the value):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <integer name="grid_column_count">2</integer>
</resources>
```

Then in the layout (I have one layout folder) xml file I configure `AndroidStaggeredGrid` as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    >
    <com.etsy.android.grid.StaggeredGridView
        android:id="@+id/grid_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:item_margin="8dp"
        app:column_count="@integer/grid_column_count" />

    <ViewStub
        android:id="@android:id/empty"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout="@layout/empty_view"/>

</FrameLayout>
```

My problem is how I can select the right size of the image (I've different sizes: 61*91, 120*178, 180*266, 510*755) to download and show based on the screen density?